# SQL - Columns are not alphabetic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

Columns are not alphabetic because I can't use "order by" with "distinct".Please help me...

My Query :

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX); 
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',MAX(CASE WHEN KullaniciAdi = '''  + p.KullaniciAdi + ''' THEN KisiAdi END) AS '  + QUOTENAME(p.KullaniciAdi) 
FROM Populer p FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'') 
set @query = 'SELECT top 100 ' + @cols + ' FROM  (   SELECT KullaniciAdi,KisiAdi,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY KullaniciAdi ORDER BY EklenmeTarihi) AS RowNum FROM Populer ) x GROUP BY RowNum ' 
EXECUTE(@query)
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: What is the problem/question?

Comment: I want sort Columns alphabetical

Comment: Remember that you sort whole _rows_, not just single columns.

Comment: When `SELECT DISTINCT`, only selected columns may be used in the ORDER BY. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: I created columns with names it should be possible.

Comment: Have (c1, c2) values (a, 1), (b, 2), (a, 3). Do `select distinct c1  ... order by c2`. What's the expected order?

Comment: **select distinct KullaniciAdi... order by KullaniciAdi** not c1 and c2. c1=c2

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can.  The key is to replace the `distinct` with `group by`.  Then use `order by`:

```
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ', MAX(CASE WHEN KullaniciAdi = '''  + p.KullaniciAdi + ''' THEN KisiAdi END) AS '  + QUOTENAME(p.KullaniciAdi) 
                   FROM Populer p
                   GROUP BY KullaniciAdi
                   ORDER BY p.KullaniciAdi
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
                  ), 1, 1, ''
                 ) ;
```

Comment: I get this error : "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."

Comment: @HasanKaanTURAN . . . I see.  You fix this with `GROUP BY`.  I updated the answer.

Comment: @HasanKaanTURAN . . . You are saying that the `GROUP BY` did *not* fix the problem?

Comment: **@GordonLinoff** Yes

Answer (score 1):

One way around this is to make your query a derived table:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT {the rest of your current query}) t
ORDER BY SomeColumn
```

Comment: My sql skills not enough.. Can u help me over my query ?